# Backing up Logic Pro X sound library

Tags: logic-pro

I've downloaded the complete Logic Pro X sound library on my Macbook Pro which takes around 57GB space. I've also gone through [this](https://music.tutsplus.com/articles/how-and-why-to-move-your-logic-pro-x-sound-libraries-to-an-external-drive--audio-19567) tutorial which says how to back up the sound library, so that you don't have to download it from scratch for a new installation. The essential idea is to:

> 1. copy *EXS Factory Samples and Ultrabeat Samples* folders from *Macintosh HD > Library > Application Support > Logic*.
> 2. copy Apple Loops from *Macintosh HD > Library > Audio > Apple Loops > Apple*.

In my case I've seen the *Logic* folder takes around 39GB, and *Apple Loops* takes 5GB. I've verified step 2, so restoring *Apple Loops* from a backup works fine. But for step 1, those two folders consume around 25GB, while the *Alchemy Samples* folder in same directory [*Logic*] is of size 14GB.

So, my question is, can I take backup for the whole *Logic* folder instead of backing up only those two folders, so that it can be restored later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a backup of the following contents in your external hard drive

> - /Library/Application Support/Logic
> - /Library/Application Support/GarageBand
> - /Library/Audio/Apple Loops
> - /Library/Audio/Impulse Responses

Once the new installation is finished, you can replace these with your backup.

---

As far as the method described in [this](https://music.tutsplus.com/articles/how-and-why-to-move-your-logic-pro-x-sound-libraries-to-an-external-drive--audio-19567) tutorial is concerned, I may have to warn you that the usage of *aliases* is not the most optimal solution out there. Symlinks, or Symbolic Links is the best way to do it.

As it is not strictly related to your query, I would leave you with a [link](https://www.logicprohelp.com/move-logics-additional-content-secondary-drive/), in case you are interested.